# Is it Haram to name someone " Rose " or " Rosario "?

Tags: names

Assalamualaikum , I wanted to know that is it haram to name someone " Rose " or  " Rosario " ? I thought the name " Rose " means the " Queen of flower "  so maybe it's permitted . And also I thought " Rosario " is permitted as well because it means " The Lady of The Rosary (  Rose garden ) " . I heard before if it's meaning is good then no names are  haram , but recently I heard that it is haram to name someone " Rose " or "Rosario " . I really liked this names but now I am confused . Please help me .

Comment: And why should it be haram? Elaborate!

Comment: I heard it is a foreign name that's why it's haram . I am not sure , I just heard that . So I am confused

Comment: If the meaning of any name is good according to Islam then it is halal ,so rose is a kind of flower and Allah's beautiful creation, so ofcourse it is halal

Answer (score 0):

**haram** means forbidden. It is not forbidden to give a child a name that is not linked to Islam.

The name coming after a flower is not forbidden.